# ¿Cuál es el análisis gramatical de "¿Cómo me le va?"?

Tags: gramática, definiciones, coloquialismos, colombia

Vivo en Colombia y con cierta frecuencia escucho la pregunta "¿Cómo me le va?" pero nadie me puede explicar por qué usa "me" en este caso.

¿Esta frase tiene alguna explicación gramatical?
¿Por qué no dicen "¿Cómo te le va?"?

Comment: Creo que está mal construido gramaticalmente si nos ceñimos a las reglas.

Comment: Esta frase es incorrecta en España y no se usa esta forma. Como dicen más abajo es `superfluo`

Comment: ¡Bienvenida a Spanish.SE! ¡Es una pregunta excelente!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según la HISPANOTECA > Gramática española

> ¿Cómo me le va?

`le` es el complemento indirecto.

`me` -> es un dativo ético

[Este “dativo ético” pertenece a los llamados dativos superfluos.](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Dativos%20superfluos.htm)

> ‘Dativo ético’, “especialmente expresivo y coloquial. Se emplea sobre todo con el pronombre de 1. persona”: Había ido el gato y se me lo ha comido; Vosotras no me salgáis de aquí.
>   A Sánchez Márquez (1872) le debemos un nuevo intento serio de diferenciar el complemento indirecto (CI) del complemento de interés (Cin). Este último “indica el interés de la acción, es decir, no es el destinatario sin más (CI), sino el afectado por la acción”. Distingue varios tipos: “Distingue la persona (varias veces la cosa) a la que afecta de alguna manera la acción; de ordinario moralmente (antiguo ‘dativo ético’), perjudicada (‘dativo de daño’), beneficiada (‘dativo de provecho’), participante (‘dativo simpatético’), adscrita, emparentada, poseedora (‘dativo posesivo’), término o sentido del movimiento (‘dativo de fin o destino’). También indica el complemento objetivo de ciertos adjetivos, paralelo al complemento directo en verbos, y hasta señala el parecer de alguien en la acción (‘dativo iudicantis’) o fin de la misma (‘dativo de fin’).»
>   [Gutiérrez Ordóñez, Salvador: “Los dativos”. En: Bosque, Ignacio / Demonte, Violeta (eds.): Gramática descriptiva de la lengua española. Madrid: Real Academia Española / Espasa Calpe. 1999, vol. 2, § 30.7.1.1]

[Relacionado](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/c%C3%B3mo%20me%20le%20va.htm)

Answer (score 1):

En Colombia el uso del "me" en este caso específicamente se refiere a que la persona a quien va dirigida la pregunta tiene alguna familiaridad con su interlocutor de manera que el "me" hace referencia a una pertenencia en el sentido de que la persona está en su "corazón". En los pueblos la gente es muy amable y feliz, de manera que todos son bienvenidos y los locales están felices de recibir a "sus" amigos. Por eso el "me".

Comment: ¿sabes Inglés?, te recomiendo que leas la segunda respuesta a esta pregunta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Como indicaron en otra respuesta, el "me" es un dativo ético, es decir, no hace falta ponerlo, pero aporta calidez en el trato, hace que la forma de preguntar sea más cariñosa.

En *lenguaje coloquial* no es incorrecto, aunque no tendría mucho sentido usarlo en la lengua escrita, máxime si estamos redactando una carta formal (a no ser que queramos imitar la oralidad).

También se debe notar que esta construcción se utiliza sólo por algunos hispanohablantes americanos. En España suena muy extraña, hasta el punto de no entenderse.