# ¿Por qué dicen "me vi la película"?

Tags: reflexivos, colombia

He escuchado varias veces a mis amigos colombianos diciendo `me vi la película`. Pero cuando les pregunto por qué dicen así, no me pueden explicar el uso de reflexivo en éste caso.

Lo he escuchado el las frases como:

> ¿Nos vemos una película mañana?
>
> ¿Te viste *tal* película ayer?

Comment: relacionada http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-an%C3%A1lisis-gramatical-de-c%C3%B3mo-me-le-va

Comment: @EmilioGort ¿entonces en un ``dativo iudicantis``?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como prometí en un comentario bajo la respuesta de **rodrigo**, he aquí un análisis que se basa en la *Gramática* de la RAE.  Aunque puede parecerlo, no es un *dativo ético*<sup>1</sup>, sino un *dativo aspectual* que también se puede llamar *dativo concordado*.

Tiene la *Gramática* una explicación impresionantemente buena, hela aquí:

> **35.7w** El dativo aspectual o concordado tiene valor enfático.  El último texto que se cita añade a la variante sin dativo (*Leímos toda la prensa*) la mayor implicación del sujeto en la acción que se menciona.  Con el pronombre *nos*, la oración sugiere, en efecto, que la lectura de la que se habla se concluyó, pero también que implicaba algún esfuerzo, que comportaba cierto mérito por parte de los que la realizaron o que había algo de particular en el hecho de hacerla.  Otras veces se sugiere que la acción descrita excede o sobrepasa en algo a lo que se considera normal (*Se fumaba dos cajetillas diarias; Se gastó el salario semanal en una juerga*):  Existen otras connotaciones similares, resultados igualmente expresivos del valor **reflexivo** que caracteriza el dativo concordado.

En resumen: utilízase para o indicar el esfuerzo implicado o el exceso o (como veremos) la completitud de la acción.  Comparemos...

- **Esfuerzo implicado**

  - Vi la película. <sub>*Mi ojo tuvo la ocasión de recibir la información visual de la película (y tal vez mi oído la aural)*</sub>
  - Me vi la película. <sub>*Hice el esfuerzo para prestar atención al contenido de la película*</sub>
- **Exceso de lo normal**

  - Gasté el dinero en las entradas. <sub>*Pagué la cantidad de dinero necesaria para conseguir las entradas*</sub>
  - Me gasté el dinero en las entradas. <sub>*Soy un tipo frugal, normalmente prefiero bajarme las películas gratis, pero aquella noche salí con una mujer bonísima*</sub>
- **Totalidad o completitud**

  - Comí las palomitas. <sub>Disfruté de unas palomitas en el cine</sub>
  - Me comí las palomitas. <sub>Disfruté de las palomitas tanto que no le dejé ni una a la mujer con que iba (por eso no hemos vuelto a salir de nuevo)</sub>

Esta última es interesante, porque alude a una limitación importante en el uso de este dativo.  Nótase en **§ 35.7x** de la *Gramática* que es obligatorio un complemento «delimitado o acotado» y que «favorecen … algunos marcadores adverbiales que denotan *completitud*».  Veamos la distinción en los siguientes ejemplos:

- **Delimitado (definitivamente finito)**

  - Anoche me vi *[ la | esta | aquella | una ]* película. <sub>*(**bien**, solo había una única película)*</sub>
  - Anoche me vi *[ las | un par de | muchísimas ]* películas. <sub>*(**bien**, había varias películas, de una cantidad fija, si no explícitamente definida)*</sub>
  - Anoche me vi películas. <sub>*(**mal**, no es una cantidad delimitada por ser general e indeterminada)*</sub>
- **Completitud (acabándolo definitivamente)**

  - Las palomitas me las comí *[ todas | por completo ]*. <sub>*(**bien**, no me quedó ninguna)*</sub>
  - Las palomitas me las comí casi todas. <sub>*(**bien**, no pude con más)*</sub>
  - Las palomitas me las comí a medias. <sub>*(**mal**, dejé muchas y por la poca cantidad, ni implica exceso ni esfuerzo ni totalidad de manera alguna)*</sub>

Para recalcar lo antemencionado, no se lo puede considerar como un dativo ético.  De hecho, es posible tener ambos dativos en una misma oración (modifico en ejemplo de la RAE para mantener el tema)<sup>2</sup>

```
 La mujer con que salí      SE       ME     comió   todas las palomitas.
[---------------------] [--------] [-----] [-----] [-------------------]
        sujeto              dat.     dat.   verbo      comp. directo
                         asp./conc. ético
```

Es decir, aquí usamos *se* para marcar (con cierta redundancia) que la mujer comió la totalidad de las palomitas.  El *me* significa que yo «beneficié» de la acción<sup>3</sup>.

Como regla general, el dativo aspectual tiene que concordar con el sujeto usando el pronombre átono reflexivo, mientras el dativo ético prescinde de tal concordancia<sup>4</sup>. Esas reglas se explicitan en los **§§ 35.7v** (aspectual) y **35.7r** (ético).

---

<sup>1.  Lo menciono porque **Emilio Gort** marcó como posiblemente relacionada la pregunta sobre «¿Cómo me le va? y luego parece haber habido confusión en los comentarios a la respuesta de Rodrigo</sup>

<sup>2.  Volviendo de nuevo a los comentarios de **Gorpik** y **Aradnix** en la respuesta de **rodrigo**, y tomando en cuenta la connotación de completitud y la distinción entre el dativo ético y aspectual, dejo como ejercicio al lector (y sin comentario adicional) el describir la diferencia entre «se la comió», «me la comió», y «se me la comió»</sup>

<sup>3.  También, es posible su análisis como un dativo de posesión (con *me* indicando que las palomitas eran mías)</sup>

<sup>4.  O al menos, no relacionarse, ya que técnicamente *le* o *les* «concuerda» gramaticalmente con un sujeto en 3ª persona, pero siendo persona(s) ajena(s) del sujeto, no admiten la forma reflexiva *se* (sin descontar la forma indirecta *se* por combinación con un pronombre átono directo en 3ª persona).</sup>

Comment: Etiqueto a @Gorpik

Comment: y a @Aradnix solo para que lean la segunda nota a pie

Comment: esto de los dativos es un poco complicado :)

Comment: @guifa Que buena cátedra. Eso de los dativos está muy interesante.

Comment: @guifa Respecto a la mención, en la nota, yo hablo del _doble sentido_ conocido como _albur_ que casi siempre tiene una connotación sexual en mi país cuando se omite el sujeto en la oración. En tus ejemplos, dices _se la comió_. Por el contexto sabemos que hablas de las palomitas, pero sin él, es costumbre que la gente haga alusión al órgano sexual masculino, y lo primero que asuma sea eso y no las palomitas, a menos que quien lo diga, capte la omisión y el riesgo y aclare a que se refería. Supongo que Gorpik se refería a algo parecido.

Comment: @guifa Respecto a la otra posibilidad _me la comió_ en terminos de albures es aun peor que la anterior. No es muy común expresarlo de esa manera. Respecto a la ultima posibilidad: _se me la comió_ es como la primera pero más redundante. Es un caso parecido al saludo: _Buenas las tenga_. Ese se los dejo de tarea.

Comment: @aradnix Era precisamente por el doble sentido que lo dejé sin comentario :)

Comment: @guifa Pues ese era el origen de mi comentario. Por toda esa gente que se regodea aplicandolo a los fuereños, y con quien hay que tner cuidado. u.u

Answer (score 4):

Es un uso de pronominal de `ver`, es decir de `verse`.

En algunas partes del mundo se usan, de forma coloquial, las formas pronominales `verse`, `leerse`, `escucharse`, incluso `comerse` o `beberse`, cuando la actividad en cuestión se hace por motivos personales (por gusto...) en lugar de para por obligación o función práctica.

Por ejemplo:

> Ayer me vi todas las películas de Harry Potter. (Las vi por que quise)
>
> ¿Viste mi documental de animales? Sí, lo vi ayer. (Lo vi por obligación)
>
> Me comí 6 hamburguesas de una sentada.
>
> Me leí el libro de un tirón.

Comment: Es percomún también con el verbo *comer*.  Creo que en todo el mundo hispanohablante se puede escuchar «me lo como», cosa que suele confundir a los no nativos.  ¡Buena explicación!

Comment: @guifa: Sí, me di cuenta de que es lo mismo que `comerse` mientras escribía, y este caso es probablemente mucho más frecuente. Curiosamente, la RAE no incluye esa acepción, aunque sí otras [formas pronominales](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=comer). ¿Será apropiada una consulta?

Comment: Creo que en este caso no es precisamente un uso pronominal aparte, es decir que para mí, comérselo carece de sentido distinto de comerlo, excepto que enfatiza quién beneficia de la consumición. P.ej. *¿No puedes comer el helado? Pues yo te lo como* (ya sé, algo raro, pero gramatical) excepto cambiando el te por me.. Luego al volver a casa puedo consultar la Gramática sobre ello.

Comment: @guifa: Supongo que podría ser en algunos casos. Por ejemplo, "comerse las uñas" es claramente reflexivo, no pronominal. Pero en "Si no quieres tu helado, me lo como yo", no hay nada reflexivo, es puramente pronominal... ¡el helado ni siquiera es mío!

Comment: A mi siempre me ha llamado la atención cuando una madre dice que su hijo "la come muy bien" (estos hijos, llegan a mutilar a sus madres a base de mordiscos?).

Comment: @Diego: Nooo, no es canibalismo. El caso que dices es un _dativo ético_ como el de la respuesta que enlaza   Emilio Gort en un comentario más arriba. La frase es "mi hijo me come muy bien", o en 3ª persona: "su hijo le come muy bien". Lo que tú escribes "la come" es además un _laísmo_, que despista un poco el análisis.

Comment: @rodrigo, gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Ojo: ese "la come muy bien" puede llevar a importantes equívocos, al menos en España.

Comment: @Gorpik y en México ni se diga. Es doble sentido puro y duro.